# Clear data of Xamarin.forms application from Android Settings is Making the Application irresponsive

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating the Xamarin.Forms application.

All the application development is done.

Nevertheless, while testing i faced some weird issue, which is like making the Application irresponsive.

Steps:

I long pressed my Application icon and i got few suggestions like Uninstall, Appinfo etc.

I clicked on App Info and navigated to the Device settings, there i clicked on Storage, there i clicked on Clear Data button, it asked my permission to clear the data and i allowed it. When i went back to the application menu and tried to open My Application it was not opening at all. it continuously stays in the splash screen itself. It's not moving to the next screen.

Here is my Android Manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/MainTheme" 
    package="My Application" 
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
      android:required="true"/>
  <application android:label="My Application" 
      android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="27"/>
</manifest>
```

I really need some suggestions, if any one had faced this before.

Comment: I am not sure the error cause by the app or the device. Test the project on another device. If still gets the error, please provide the code sample for us to test. If works well on another device, you could reset the device to debug the app again.